# Getting known library paths from ldconfig for use with dlopen

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, posix, dlopen

I have a program written in C that uses dlopen for loading plug-in modules. When the library is dynamically loaded, it runs constructor code which register pointer to structure with function implementations with the main application by use of exported function. I want to use absolute path for specifying the file to dlopen.

Then I have other part of the program with takes file, determine if it is ELF, then looks into the ELF header for specific ELF section, read this section and extract from it pertinent information. This way it filters only shared libraries which I have previously tagged as a plug-in module.

However, I am solving a problem how to discover them on the fly (in portable Linux way, i.e. it will run on Debian and on Fedora too and so on) from the main program. I have been thinking about using ldconfig for this. (As the modules will be installed by way of distro packaging system, APT for example.) Is there any way how to programmatically get the string list of known libraries from C program other than directly reading the /etc/ld.co.cache file? I was thinking that maybe there is some header library which will give char** when I ask.

Or, maybe is there any better solution to my problem?

(I am proponent of using standard system components that programming one-off solutions which will need support in the future.)

Comment: Don't programs usually require plugins to reside in a location specified by a configuration parameter?

Comment: Probably yes. And it then probably can be done by creating symlink to the library in some specific location. However, I think that has it's own problems. Like you may want to have the modules and program which uses them as plug-ins as separated entities, so for example they can be installed and uninstalled independently.